# remove a specific text from <td> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove a specific set of characters from a div elements. They contains dates with time and I'd like to remove the time part. 
Here is how I try it but it is not working.

```
$("td").each(function( i ) {
            $(this).remove('12:00:00 AM');

        }
```

Any suggestion is welcome. 
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) `$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/pattern_to_replace/, ''))`

Comment: also http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`tds=document.getElementsByTagName("td");`
getElementsByTagName returns a nodeList not an array, it does not have a `forEach` method on it.

you can this natively by writing the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(currentTd) {
   currentTd.innerHTML = currentTd.innerHTML.replace('12:00:00 AM', "");
});
```